# HDP- Datanodes are crashing

Tags: hadoop, linux-kernel, centos6, hortonworks-data-platform, hawq

We have 4 nodes Hadoop cluster. 
2 Master nodes
2 data nodes 
After sometimes we found that our data nodes are failing. then, we go and see the log section it always tell  cannot allocate memory.

**ENV**

```
HDP 2.3.6 VERSION 
HAWQ 2.0.0 VERSION 
linux os : centos 6.0
```

**Getting following error**

Data nodes are crashing WITH following logs

```
os::commit_memory(0x00007fec816ac000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

**Memory Info**

**vm_overcommit ratio is 2**

```
MemTotal:       30946088 kB
MemFree:        11252496 kB
Buffers:          496376 kB
Cached:         11938144 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         15023232 kB
Inactive:        3116316 kB
Active(anon):    5709860 kB
Inactive(anon):   394092 kB
Active(file):    9313372 kB
Inactive(file):  2722224 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      15728636 kB
SwapFree:       15728636 kB
Dirty:               280 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       5705052 kB
Mapped:           461876 kB
Shmem:            398936 kB
Slab:             803936 kB
SReclaimable:     692240 kB
SUnreclaim:       111696 kB
KernelStack:       33520 kB
PageTables:       342840 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    31201680 kB
Committed_AS:   26896520 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       73516 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359538628 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   2887680 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        6132 kB
DirectMap2M:     2091008 kB
DirectMap1G:    29360128 kB
```

Comment: 30GB is pretty small.  How much memory do you have allocated to the other processes like the datanode heap size?  Do you have other processes running?

Comment: datanode heap size  is 2 GB . we have scheduled few Batch job( approx 50 in counts ) in it on 1 hour frequency

Comment: What kind of batch job?  Do you have other Hadoop processes running?  You really haven't provided enough information to debug the issue.